# Definition of limit point of a subset

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading real analysis and stuck in the definition of limit point.

**Definition 1.** A point $P \in \mathbb{R}$ is said to be a limit point of a subset $S$
of $\mathbb{R}$ if every neighbourhood of $P$ has a point of $S$ other than $P$ itself.

**Definition 2** A point $P \in \mathbb{R}$ is said to be a limit point of a subset $S$
of $\mathbb{R}$ if every neighbourhood of $P$ has an infinite number of points of subset $S$

These two definitions are given equivalent in the book. However , they don't seem to be equivalent to each other.

The first definition requires only presence of only a single element of $S$ in any neighbourhood of $P$ (if it was a limit of subset) while the second definition requires presence of infinitely many elements of $S$ in any neighbourhood of $P$.

Comment: They are. Take the first definition and consider an infinite sequence of smaller neighborhoods within the one guaranteed by the hypothesis.

Comment: Exactly as @JohnDouma said - the first definition guarantee's no matter how small the neighbourhood of $p$ is, there will always be another element other than $p$ common to $S$ within this neighbourhood. For example, take ${a,p}$ to be the elements common to the neighbourhood and $S$. If you ensure a new neighbourhood of $p$ is smaller than the distance between ${a}$ and ${p}$ then $a$ will no longer be in this neighbourhood, but definition $1$ guarantees we can find yet another point (which of course will have to be distinct from $a$). So infinitely many, as per def. 2

Comment: @JohnDouma , Thanks , I understood !!

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose  , book also mentions that limit of                                             S = {(-1)^n | n ∈ N } is 1 and -1. As far as i can understand , all neighbourhoods of 1 doesnot contain atleast one member of S except 1. Why is then 1 the limit of the sequence ?

Comment: $1$ counts as being in its own neighborhood.

Comment: Elaborate please @LieutenantZipp , definition says the limit except 1.